# Javascript RegExp: Word boundaries and punctuation marks

Tags: javascript, regex

Im trying to use javascript's RegExp to match full words but it doesn't work when those words have punctuation as the boundary. I.e.

```
(new RegExp("\\b"+RegExp.escape("why not")+"\\b", 'i')).test("why not you foolish")
```

Correctly matches. And:

```
(new RegExp("\\b"+RegExp.escape("why not")+"\\b", 'i')).test("why nots you foolish")
```

Correctly does not match. The problem is this doesn't work when the word ends with a "?":

```
(new RegExp("\\b"+RegExp.escape("why not?")+"\\b", 'i')).test("why not? you foolish")
```

Any suggestions?

NOTE: I am using this function to escape:

```
# Escape characters for regexp
RegExp.escape = (text) ->
  text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&")
```

Comment: is RegExp.escape something you've defined on your own? As is, RegExp has no method 'escape': [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Methods)  If so, could you show us the source and we could help you find the problem there.

Comment: Sorry yeah i forgot to include that, I updated the code above with that now though.

Comment: BTW: foolproof, but excessive RegExp.escape: `replace(/\W/g, function(m){var c=m.charCodeAt(0),r=c.toString(16);for(;c<4096;c<<=4)r="0"+r;return "\\u"+r;});`

Answer (score 3):

`?` has a special meaning in RegExp and should be escaped.

Ok, I see, you're trying to escape it... but not all browsers have this method `RegExp.escape` built-in and it seemed, this is the prolbem. Cause

```
(new RegExp("\\b"+"why not\?"+"\\b", 'i')).test("why not? you foolish")
```

works as supposed (return true).

Here's a code I used:

```
if (typeof RegExp.escape == "undefined") {
    RegExp.escape = function(str) {
        return str.replace(/([()\[\]\\\/+*?.-])/g, "\\$1");
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah you're right! The two issues now tho are that it wont match "\?" to "?" AND its matching "why not\?" to "why not?sososo" which it shouldnt be. Any ideas?

Comment: *Just as planned* ;-) Punctuation marks are not considered as word boundaries. That's how `\b` works. In first case it matches, cause there's next word right after the `?`. In the second case there're no words and hence no boundaries. You may use `^|\\b...$|\\b` instead of `\\b...\\b` for second case, though.

Comment: Thanks! I dont suppose you have any brilliant thoughts on how to match just hte single punctuation marks as well?

Comment: @kirilloid: punctuation marks next to legal word characters DO indicate a word boundary at that position. ?this? has two of 'em.

Answer (score 1):

"?" is a special character for Regex. I believe you need to escape it.